# What is an Outs Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **Outs** word.
Here is a list of examples:

| OUTS | NOT OUTS |
| --- | --- |
| bar | allow |
| boil | freeze |
| cool | hot |
| guru | initiate |
| ingrate | grateful |
| lich | skeleton |
| rage | serenity |
| ruins | creates |

And a CSV version:

```
OUTS, NOT OUTS
bar, allow
boil, freeze
cool, hot
guru, initiate
ingrate, grateful
lich, skeleton
rage, serenity
ruins, creates
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is an **Outs** word or not? Why is it called an **Outs** word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Outs Word is a word which:

> is an **anagram of the starting letters of the name of a South American country**. It is called an 'Outs Word' since 'Outs' is itself an anagram of the first four letters of '**SOUT**H'.

This can be seen as follows:

> bar --> **BRA**zil
>  boil --> **BOLI**via
>  cool --> **COLO**mbia
>  guru --> **URUG**uay
>  ingrate --> **ARGENTI**na
>  lich --> **CHIL**e
>  rage --> **ARGE**ntina
>  ruins --> **SURIN**ame

The 'Not Outs Words' do not comply with this rule.

Just for fun, a further topical example for this site would be:

> **REP**, from **PER**u!

Comment: A quick question, how are you so quick to view new puzzles, do you have a way it can notify you via sms?

Comment: Very nice! That is correct ;)

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Ha, no, just luck I saw this one shortly after it was posted! I had the site still open in a browser tab while I was doing other things and noticed the '(1)' pop up in the tab title. No notifications here! :)